# Anaconda/conda create environment with django 1.11 with cli command

Tags: python, django, package, conda, environment

I'm trying to create a new environment using conda with django package 1.11.13.
Using `conda create --name myEnv django` is offering a django v2x, how can I specify the package version?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is:

```
conda create --name myEnv django=1.11.3
```

myEnv is the environment name, 1.11.3 is the django version I'm trying to get, I was just missing the (=) sign